# How to transform decimal to exponential in linux bash

Tags: bash, decimal, exponential

is possible to transform a decimal number in exponential?

> 11.2345 into 0.112345E+2?

Thank you

Comment: Try : `printf "%e" 11.2345`

Answer (score 3):

Use `printf` command it allows you to provide a formatting like in case of C `printf`, there you have a `%e` option, that prints in exponential notation:

```
printf %e 11.2345
```

This will result in:

```
1.123450e+01
```

Answer (score 2):

[krzyk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38528499/revisions) helpfully suggests use of **`printf '%e'`**, but this has the following **implications**:

<sup>Note: `printf '%E'` essentially works the same, except that it uses *uppercase* `E` in the output.</sup>

- It uses ***6* decimal places in the output** by default, irrespective of how many significant digits the input number had.

  - e.g., `printf %e 1` yields `1.000000e+00`
  - You *can* control the number of output decimal places *explicitly*:

    - e.g., `printf %.1e 129` yields `1.3e+02`
  - However, there is ***no* mechanism to use exactly as many significant digits as the input number has**.
- The output number invariably uses ***normalized* scientific notation**, where the significand (the number before the `e` / `E`) has an **integer part `>= 1` and `< 9`** and the **exponent is always a two-digit (decimal) integer with an explicit sign**:

  - e.g., `printf %.1e 66` yields `6.6e+01` (in an English locale)
  - There is ***no* way to apply a *different* normalization** to the significand, such as starting it with `0.` (as used in the question).
- `printf %e` respects the current locale, which means that **both the input number must be - and the output will be - formatted according to the rules of the *current locale***, notably with respect to the decimal mark (`.` vs. `,`) and thousands separator (`,` vs. `.` vs. `<space>`).

  - e.g., `(export LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8; printf %.2e 66,1)`  yields `6,61e+01`, using the German locale - note the use of `,` as the decimal mark in both the in- and output.

---

Find **locale-aware Bash function `toNumSci()`** at the bottom, which addresses *some* of these limitations; specifically, it allows you to preserve the significant number of input digits and to opt into `0.d...` significand normalization.

Applied to the example from the question, you'd use:

```
$ toSciNum 11.2345 1 # 1 opts into `0.d...` significand normalization
0.112345E+02 # same number of significant digits, 0.d...-normalized
```

<sup>Note: The only deviation from the question's output format is the use of a two-digit left-padded-with-zeros exponent.</sup>

**Source code** of `toNumSci()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Usage:
#   toSciNum number [zeroDotFormat [numSigDigits]]
# Converts the specified number (float or integer) to normalized scientific 
# notation ([+-]d.d...E+-dd), preserving the number of significant digits in 
# the input.
# Optionally you can control the number of significant digits explicitly
# and choose alternative output format [+-]0.d...E+-dd
# Note: The input number must use locale-appropriate formatting with
#       respect to decimal mark and thousands grouping, if applicable.
#       Similarly, the output number is formatted locale-appropriately. 
# Examples:
#   toSciNum 123    # -> 1.23E+02
#   toSciNum 123 1  # -> 0.123E+03
#   toSciNum -66.7 0 4  # -> -6.670+01
toSciNum() {

  local num=$1 zeroDotFormat=${2:-0} numSigDigits=$3
  local digitsOnly fmtStr numSci decMark significand exponent sign=

  # Determine the number of significant digits.
  # If not specified, use the same number as in the input number.
  if [[ -z $numSigDigits ]]; then
    digitsOnly=${num//[!0-9]} # Remove all non-digit characters...
    numSigDigits=${#digitsOnly} # ... and count them.
  fi

  # Construct the printf format string.
  # Note that the number of decimal places is the number of
  # significant digits minus 1, because in the normalized scientific notation
  # that %e / %E produce, there by definition always 1 integer digit. 
  fmtStr="%.$(( numSigDigits - 1 ))E"

  # Create the normalized scientific notation representation (d.dddd ...) 
  # and store it in var. $numSci.
  printf -v numSci "$fmtStr"  "$num"

  # If the 0.ddd format is requested instead, transform the result.
  if (( zeroDotFormat )); then
    [[ $numSci == -* ]] && sign='-'
    # Extract the decimal mark from the result.
    decMark=${numSci:1:1}
    # Extract the exponent from the result
    significand=${numSci%E*}
    exponent=${numSci##*E}
    # Construct the new significand as [-]0.ddd
    significand="${sign}0${decMark}${significand//[!0-9]}"
    # Construct the new exponent (to which +1 must be added to compensate, now 
    # that the significand is effectively being divided by 10.
    printf -v exponent '%+03d' $(( 1 + 10#${exponent} ))
    # Assemble the pieces to form the new number.
    numSci="${significand}E${exponent}"
  fi

  printf '%s\n' "$numSci"
}
```

Comment: Hat off to a slick implementation.